# Is it possible to using sqlite spellfix in Android app?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an Android app and I would like to using spellfix module for sqlite. Is it possible? What is the general principles of usage sqlite modules?

Comment: @JeremyD, currently I just trying to find any information, but has no success.

Comment: i will try today lets see if it's work

Comment: @coder5, please let me know about your expirience.

Comment: i just trying using sqlite manager app and suddently stop after touch spellfix table , i think it's not working in android but i'll try develop app from scract, i got same idea with you :D

Comment: @coder5, I think here is needed to using NDK. But currently I have no any additional info.

Comment: You can check this 
 https://github.com/vinaysshenoy/SQLiteSpellfix. They are using ndk to implement this